# libnl takes time to see a disconnected client

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ios, embedded

I am working on an embedded device, with a custom OS (Yocto on iMX6).

The device use hostapd to create a WLAN.
I use libnl to list the connected WiFi clients, my code is based on `iw` to get the clients MAC addresses.

The detection works pretty fine when Linux PC clients or Android clients connect and disconnect. But with iOS devices, the disconnection takes a long time:

- Connection is detected;
- Disconnection is sometimes detected (when I turn the WiFi button OFF on iOS device) and the device is seen as "not connected" in my app;
- Disconnection is sometimes not detected. The device is still seen although the WiFi is turned OFF on iOS. The command `iw dev wlan0 station dump |grep Station` also shows the unconnected client. A ping on the device shows that the device is not responding. nmap command also shows that the device is not connected. The disconnection occurs 1-2 min after.

This is the hostapd logs when the connection with iOS occurs:

```
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: authenticated
HT: Forty MHz Intolerant is set by STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e in Association Request
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

When the disconnection is successful:

```
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
```

When the disconnection is timed out:

```
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: disassociated due to inactivity
wlan0: STA 04:69:f8:0a:1e:6e IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
```

To compare, this is a connection/disconnection with an Android device (note that there is no inactivity timeout):

```
# Connect
wlan0: STA 74:04:2b:ea:95:86 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan0: STA 74:04:2b:ea:95:86 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 2)
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 74:04:2b:ea:95:86
wlan0: STA 74:04:2b:ea:95:86 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
# Disconnect 
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 74:04:2b:ea:95:86
```

This is what I tried for now:

- Changing ap_max_inactivity to 5 seconds -> improved the disconnection time to 10-15 sec
- refreshing the ARP cache (no success)

Is it a matter of hostapd configuration? I don't know which parameter modify.
Or maybe this issue is related to iOS.